# Json data not printed out

Tags: java, json

I have some trouble printing out JSON data and I can't seem to figure out what I did wrong. The out.pring(test) seems to print out fine. However, out.println(val.getJsonString("country")); doesn't seems to print out anything.I access the JSON from a URL, I want to parse these data into an HTML table and print them out. Before creating the table I want to check if I am actually getting the data or not. It turns out that the data cannot be printed and I can't seem to find out why this line is not printing out anything.

```
out.println(val.getJsonString("country"))
```

Full code:

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.json.*;


public class StatesServlet extends HttpServlet {
    public void doGet (HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws ServletException, IOException
    {

        PrintWriter out = res.getWriter();
    try{
        String url="http://test.com/all.json";
            URL server = new URL(url);
            URLConnection connection = server.openConnection();
            InputStream file_in = connection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader buffered = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(file_in));
            StringBuilder test = new StringBuilder();
            String line ="";

            while((line = buffered.readLine())!= null){
                test.append(line+"\n");


            }
            buffered.close();
            out.println(test);

        JsonReader reader = Json.createReader(new StringReader(test.toString()));
            JsonObject jObject = reader.readObject();
            reader.close();
            JsonArray result = jObject.getJsonObject("RestResponse").getJsonArray("result");
            for (JsonObject val : result.getValuesAs(JsonObject.class)) {

        out.println(val.getJsonString("country"));


            }


        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }



    }
}
```

json below:

```html
{
"RestResponse": {
 "messages": ["test", "test"],
 "result": [{
  "country": "test",
  "name": "test",
  "largest_city": "test ",
  "capital": "test"
 }, {
  "country": "test",
  "name": "test",
  "largest_city": "test ",
  "capital": "test"

 }]
}
}
```

Comment: Currently you're swallowing all exceptions, just printing them to the console. Are you checking the console for any exceptions? (It's almost certainly not a good idea to catch that exception and swallow it - if you're getting an error, you should probably respond to the user with an error page too.)

Comment: When I remove the exception it throws an error : javax.json.stream.JsonParsingException: Unexpected char 60 at (line no=1, column no=1, offset=0)

Comment: can you validate the json or show us here?

Comment: i've update the json

Comment: your json is invalid. Validate it with https://jsonlint.com/

Comment: I've validated the json but it still throws the the same error